# Proving that any polynomial $p:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is not bounded, but its restriction to any bounded set is bounded

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $p(t) =  a_0+\dots +a_nt^n, a_n\neq 0,$ a polynomial with degree $n>0$. Prove that $p:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is not bounded, but for any bounded subset $X\subset \mathbb{R}$ the restriction $p\vert X$ is bounded.

I want to prove this in very **elementary terms**. I mean, without using the notion of limit or even continuity. I can only show this with "strong" results. Is it possible with elementary terms?

Comment: Absolutely: use the (generalised) triangle inequality.

Comment: @Bernard: what's the "generalised triangle inequality"? (Isn't the good old-fashioned one good enough to answer this question?)

Comment: @Rob Arthan: I mean the trivial generalisation to a sum of $n$ terms. I used the phrasing because of the requirement of *very* elementary terms. So I thought that what goes without saying for some might go better saying it for others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $t>1$, $|p(t)|\geq {{|p(t)|}\over t^{n-1}}\geq |a_n|t-(\sum_{i=0}^{i=n-1}|a_i|)$. This implies that $p(t)$ is unbounded. 
If $X$ is bounded by $c>0$, $p(t)\leq |a_0|+|a_1|c+...+|a_n|c^n$.